# How can we trigger `receive()` function in a smart contract when sender is a smart contract as well?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, receive

Let's say we have the following contract that is the receiver:

```
contract Receiver {
    bool public received;

    receive() external payable {
        received = true;
    }
}
```

How do we implement the sending smart contract in order to be able to trigger `receive()`? Assuming that we use the following template for the sender contract.

```
contract Sender {
   function send(address payable target) external payable {
        // insert code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the following options for sending ETH via Solidity:

- `transfer(...)` (forwards fixed 2300 gas, throws error)
- `send(...)` (forwards fixed 2300 gas, returns bool)
- `call(...)` (forwards all gas or set gas, returns bool)

In order to trigger `receive()`, we need to make sure that the gas forwarded is enough to execute the code inside `receive()` on the receiver contract. Therefore, we would need to implement the sender using `call(...)` as follows:

```
contract Sender {
   function send(address payable target) external payable {
        (bool success,)= target.call{value: msg.value}("");
        require(success);
    }
}
```